# proving $J=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x}}dx<2$

Tags: calculus

If $\displaystyle I = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x}}dx$ and $\displaystyle J=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x}}dx$. Then prove that $\displaystyle I<\frac{2}{3}$ and $\displaystyle J<2$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Using $\displaystyle \sin x <x\;\forall x\in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$

So $\displaystyle \sin x<x\Rightarrow \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x}}<\frac{x}{\sqrt{x}}=\sqrt{x}$

So $\displaystyle I = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x}}dx <\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x}dx = \frac{2}{3}$

So $\displaystyle I <\frac{2}{3}$

But I did not understand how can i prove $\displaystyle J = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x}}dx <2$?

Comment: Are you sure? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E1%5Ccos%7Bx%7D%2F%5Csqrt+%7Bx%7D

Comment: Thanks  Joseph Curwen , I have edited it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrate $\displaystyle J=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx$ by parts. It gives :

$$
\begin{align*}
J &= \left[ 2\sqrt{x}\cos(x) \right]_{0}^{1} + \int_{0}^{1} 2\sqrt{x}\sin(x) \, dx \\
&= 2 \Big( \cos(1) + \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{x}\sin(x) \, dx \Big) \\
\end{align*}
$$

On $]0,1[$, $0 < \sqrt{x} < 1$ and $\sin(x) > 0$. So, $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{x}\sin(x) \, dx < \int_{0}^{1} \sin(x) \, dx = - \cos(1)+1$. It proves that

$$ \cos(1) + \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{x}\sin(x) \, dx < 1 $$

As a consequence, $J < 2$.

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle J = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x}}dx$

Since $ cos x < 1 $ for x = 0+  to 1

Now divide both side by $\sqrt x$ and    Integrate both side than

You will get J < 2